# Создание словаря по данным из txt файла python

Tags: python, парсер, словари, текст

есть txt файл с данным собержимым:

```
UUU F      CUU L      AUU I      GUU V
UUC F      CUC L      AUC I      GUC V
UUA L      CUA L      AUA I      GUA V
UUG L      CUG L      AUG M      GUG V
UCU S      CCU P      ACU T      GCU A
UCC S      CCC P      ACC T      GCC A
UCA S      CCA P      ACA T      GCA A
UCG S      CCG P      ACG T      GCG A
UAU Y      CAU H      AAU N      GAU D
UAC Y      CAC H      AAC N      GAC D
UAA Stop   CAA Q      AAA K      GAA E
UAG Stop   CAG Q      AAG K      GAG E
UGU C      CGU R      AGU S      GGU G
UGC C      CGC R      AGC S      GGC G
UGA Stop   CGA R      AGA R      GGA G
UGG W      CGG R      AGG R      GGG G
```

и есть функция которая должна по данным собрать словарь по типу F: UUU, UUC; I: AUU, AUC и т.д

```
def translate_rna_to_protein(rna):
    protein = ""
    p = open('rna_codon_table.txt', 'r')
    for line in p:
        for i in line.split():
            if line.split().index(i) % 2 == 0:
                print('1')
            else:
                print('2')

    return protein
```

однако первый элемент строки является ключом для ещё не созданного значения. Нужна помощь в реализации такого словаря для последующего использования.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166709/398802

Comment: в вашем файле данные расположены в четырех столбцах или вы это для наглядности так в вопросе показали?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, откуда вы это задание получили?) я просто тоже такое делал

Comment: Порядочное бы было тоже закрыть файл.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = open('data.txt', 'r')
protein = {}
for line in p:
    data = line.split()
    for v, k in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
        protein.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(protein)
```

Comment: Порядочное бы было тоже закрыть файл.:-)

Comment: @MarianD Блин, а питон не гарантирует закрытие файла при сборке мусора. Когда `p` выйдет из области видимости по завершении функции он его может забыть ? Если так, то конечно печально и надо закрывать руками

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()

res = [(a, [z[0] for z in b]) 
       for a,b in groupby(
                      sorted(
                          re.findall(r"(\w+)\s(\w+)", data), 
                          key=lambda x: x[1]), 
                      key=lambda x: x[1])]
res = dict(res)
```

---

результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
{'A': ['GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'],
 'C': ['UGU', 'UGC'],
 'D': ['GAU', 'GAC'],
 'E': ['GAA', 'GAG'],
 'F': ['UUU', 'UUC'],
 'G': ['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'],
 'H': ['CAU', 'CAC'],
 'I': ['AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA'],
 'K': ['AAA', 'AAG'],
 'L': ['CUU', 'CUC', 'UUA', 'CUA', 'UUG', 'CUG'],
 'M': ['AUG'],
 'N': ['AAU', 'AAC'],
 'P': ['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'],
 'Q': ['CAA', 'CAG'],
 'R': ['CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'AGA', 'CGG', 'AGG'],
 'S': ['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC'],
 'Stop': ['UAA', 'UAG', 'UGA'],
 'T': ['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'],
 'V': ['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG'],
 'W': ['UGG'],
 'Y': ['UAU', 'UAC']}
```